# How do you set a Nullable Dependency Property to Null?

Tags: c#, dependency-properties, nullable

So I thought this would be straight forward enough but apparently setting a dependency property to null causes an exception.

```
    public int? Value
    {
        get => (int?)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        set {SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(default(int?), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValueChanged)));
```

When the above code is used and the `Value` setter is called with a `value` of `null` I get the following exception

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'`

Which makes entirely no sense. If it's a `Nullable object` then by definition, I should be able to set it to null.

So my question is, is there a way to have a dependency property with a nullable type while also being able to set it to null?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Please provide more details.

Comment: Is there any place (either binding or OnValueChanged) you are accessing your Value with Value.Value?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `typeof(object)` with `typeof(int?)` when you register the dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int?), typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(default(int?), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValueChanged)));
```

Setting an `int?` property to `null` or `default(int?)` should work.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. Same exception, same location

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: Please show us how and where you get the exception then.

Comment: I did, it's in the code above. When that dependency property is set to null, I get this exception

Comment: Nope, when the value is set to null

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: Where and when do you set `Value` to `null`? Please provide a code snippet. And tell us what XAML framework you are using.

Comment: Are you trying to assing `Value` to something like `nullableInt.Value`? Accessing `Value` of an `int?` that doesn't have any value will get you an exception like this.